# ASP.NET Core support in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

Now that ASP.NET Core is shipped with VS 2017(getting released on March), How long will they support ASP.NET Core in VS 2015?

I mean project.json will no longer be used, then do we need to move existing projects to VS 2017 and dont use VS 2015 to work with ASP.NET Core.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Visual Studio 2015 will only support .NET Core <= 1.1 (ie. project.json). If you wish to use .csproj based .NET Core projects you will need to use Visual Studio 2017. You can read about the .NET Core Roadmap [here](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/roadmap.md).

You can stick with project.json and Visual Studio 2015. But if you want to move to .NET Core 2.0 you will need to open your project with Visual Studio 2017 which can migrate it to the new `.csproj` format. You can read about the migration process in [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/11/16/announcing-net-core-tools-msbuild-alpha/).

Visual Studio 2017 will also provide stable RTM tooling for .NET Core 1.0 (note that the tooling in Visual Studio 2015 is only in preview). There is another interesting [blog post here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/10/19/net-core-tooling-in-visual-studio-15/) which discusses the move to the new project format, Joe Morris from Microsoft confirms there are no plans to have VS 2015 support the build/project system.

**Update**

With the release of Visual Studio 2019, the latest .NET Core SDKs are not supported in Visual Studio 2015 *or* 2017. Here is the [compatibility matrix](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/3124):

[image: Compatibility Matrix]

Comment: means we have 2 options to work either in VS 2015 or VS 2017? Only if .csproj needed I should be moving to VS 2017

Comment: @MithunPattankar basically it is recommended to update to VS 2017 .csproj sooner rather than later, especially if you want to take advantage of the newer versions of .NET Core, the updated tooling, csproj project format, .NET Standard 2.0, etc.

Comment: thanks, its like move ahead !! On official machines, we need to give specific reason why to move VS 2017 & purpose of migrations (part of process). Clear explanation !!