# visual studio 2015 .net core tools download location?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, .net-core

Does anyone know where I can find the latest download for Visual Studio 2015 .NET Core Tools. On 2/3/2017 I downloaded Dot Net Tools Visual Studio 2015 Preview 2 from www.microsoft.com/net/core. That page at that time had three choices - Visual Studio 2015, Visual Studio 2017, and Command line / other. I now need to install the tools on a different system and cannot find them anywhere. The .NET Core download page now only has two options - Visual Studio 2017 and Command line /other. Does anyone know where I can download the tools today and where I can expect to find a release version sometime in the future?

Comment: .NET Core has dropped support for the project.json, and Visual Studio 2015 was not updated to support the MsBuild based project files fully. Unfortunately, you'll have to upgrade to VS2017 for full .NET Core support: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42337225/736079

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That link off of the old page was:

https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=827546

And is associated with: NET Core 1.0.1 - VS 2015 Tooling Preview 2 - Microsoft Go!

At the preview 2.0.3 level.

Comment: Is the Release Candidate is available?