# How to use EF Core with Visual Studio 2015 in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, coreclr

I have ASP.NET Core Web API Application and i would like to use EF Core to perform CRUD operations. But EF Core documentation says i need VS 2017 [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db)

I have VS 2015 Community. So when i try configuring EF Core i'm getting error

> Startup project 'src\MyWebAPI' is an ASP.NET Core or .NET Core
>   project for Visual Studio 2015. This version of the Entity Framework
>   Core Package Manager Console Tools doesn't support these types of
>   projects.

I have never used code first approach and i have been using Db first approach in classic .NET.

The ASP.NET Core application has very small database with only 1 table and I just want to do CRUD operations on this table. I don't care about migration. Updating to VS 2017 is not option for me right now.

What are my options here to do CRUD operations with VS 2015 using EF Core?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core support in Visual Studio 2015?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337211/asp-net-core-support-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: @GertArnold the link you refered talk about asp.net core support in vs 2015. My question was related how to use EF Core in VS 2015. Its not duplicate question.

Comment: Ensure you're using version 1.0.0 of `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet`