# visual studio 2015 with .Net Core

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I have installed vs 2015 professional, but i am not able to find .Net Core in templates window.[vs 2015 professional template window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMjBZ.jpg)

Comment: you should use visual studio 2017 if you want to use asp.net core 2.0

Comment: I heard that VS2015 Update 3 can support .Net Core

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337211/asp-net-core-support-in-visual-studio-2015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.net core is not supported by default in Visual Studio 2015

you have to install [.NET Standard Support for Visual Studio 2015](https://aka.ms/dotnet-standard-support-vs2015-2.0.0-win-x86)

Comment: I heard that VS2015 Update 3 can support .Net Core

Comment: @Venkatesh: That's what he said, you need to install the MSI from https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core!!