# ASP.NET Core MVC 2.0 in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, editor

**Is there any way to create an asp.net core mvc (model-view-controller web application) based on version 2.0 of asp.net core mvc in visual studio 2015?**

I want to create an asp.net core mvc version 2.0 because i have heard there are many changes in this release. vs2017 runs too slow and laggy on my computer so i would like to find a way to create my project under vs2015. I have tried to find a way to install it's libraries but i couldn't because i'm actuality trying to learn it. I have also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337211/asp-net-core-support-in-visual-studio-2015) question in stackoverflow but it turns to me that he wants to migrate a project and not to start a new project, so my question differs from that question in this point that i want to create a new asp.net core 2.0 mvc project from scratch but he has tried to migrate an existing project.

Comment: Could you reformat your question and correct some of the grammar so it's a bit more readable? As it stands, it's kind of hard to read.

Comment: sorry, i was editing it. i will try to enhance it a bit more too. so every one would be able to understand it.

Comment: While installing vs2017 choose only web development option will be only 6 to 8 GB setup which will work perfectly along with that install your asp.net core 1.1 and 2.0 package which will be round 200 MB.

Comment: @Saineshwar i already tried that but it was too laggy for my pc.

Comment: @MortezaAcademia what is configration of pc

Comment: @Saineshwar CPU: Pentium 3 with 1.6Ghz Dual Core, 4GBs of RAM, 1GB AMD graphic accelerator, 512 GB of HDD.

Comment: @MortezaAcademia need to upgrade it to at-least i3 or i5 and 8GB ram will work well

Comment: @Saineshwar yup. thank you. but i cant afford it now  i already got a new way and figured out to use visual studio Code instead, and its lightweight and working fine, it hope it would be useful for people in similar situation to me.

Comment: @o_O it's not duplicate. i have already read it and i have explained in the questions how it's different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching more and more ways to my end, I concluded to use Microsoft [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and [.NET Core 2.0.0 SDK](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core) alongside With [C# Extension For Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.csharp). This is a very simple and light weight playground to develop Asp.net Core 2.0 apps both in windows and Linux operating systems.

for a comprehensive tutorial to installing and developing core 2.0 apps is vsCode see [Create an ASP.NET Core MVC app with Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app-xplat/)