# Error occurred while trying to run asp.net core in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I installed .NET Core SDK in Visual Studio 2015, but it refuse to start/debug, if I create a new project it will show me an error[image]

Comment: @NightOwl888 Visual Studio 2015 only works with the preview build SDK.

Comment: You have to give up the idea of doing .NET Core in Visual Studio 2015. Switch to Visual Studio 2017, Rider, or at least Visual Studio Code, and then install latest .NET Core SDK to get started from scratch. All bits you tried in Visual Studio 2015 are long dead and please forget about them.

Comment: See [ASP.NET Core support in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42337225). Lex Li is correct, there is no support for anything but old .NET Core SDKs <= 1.1 in VS 2015.