# nopcommerce 4.0 source code is zip file extracted but in NopCommerce sln file is not loaded in Visual studio 2015 issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nopcommerce

I am facing a problem while opening the NopCommerce solution file from Visual studio 2015 
The error message is

> One or more projects in the solution where not loaded please to see
>   the output windows for details

Output window error

> D:\nopcommerce\Presentation\Nop.Web\Nop.Web.csproj : error  : The
>   default XML namespace of the project must be the MSBuild XML
>   namespace. If the project is authored in the MSBuild 2003 format,
>   please add xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"
>   to the  element. If the project has been authored in the old
>   1.0 or 1.2 format, please convert it to MSBuild 2003 format.

I have also shared screenshot please till how to solve error[screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6h2C.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

NopCommerce 4.0 is built on ASP.NET Core 2.0.

VS 2015 supports only ASP.NET Core <=1.1. You need to install VS 2017 to run NopCommerce 4.0.

Here is the link to official documentation

https://www.nopcommerce.com/boards/t/49380/nopcommerce-400-is-released.aspx

[ASP.NET Core support in Visual Studio 2015?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337211/asp-net-core-support-in-visual-studio-2015)

Comment: Thanks to Balaji i appreciated to your statement.