# How to add .NET Core to Visual Studio 2015 Pro

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, .net-core, visual-studio-2015, installation

I want to install .NET Core in Visual Studio 2015 Pro, to implement Service worker for Linux.

When I go to official [download page](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1) of microsoft, they are showing everything confusing, not sure what to download.
See below screeshot

[image]

Please suggest how to install .Net Core?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft only [supports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42337211/asp-net-core-support-in-visual-studio-2015) .NET Core development on Visual Studio 2015 up to .NET Core 1.1, meanwhile .NET Core Worker Service is introduced on [.NET Core 3.0](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/demystifying-the-new-net-core-3-worker-service/). Since the only [currently supported](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) .NET Core with Worker Service is .NET 3.1, you will need to use .NET Core 3.1, which are only supported by the latest VS 2019. So either ask your company if they can provide you with the license for VS 2019 Pro, get VS 2019 Community if you're eligible, or otherwise use VS Code.

Comment: Is it possible to use VS Code with .NET Core? Can I develop Worker using VSC IDE?

Comment: Yes, the template is available through [.NET CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=netcore-cli#worker-service-template), once created it's just yet another .NET Core project supported by VS Code

Comment: I am not getting 'worker service template' in VS2019 Enterprise. How can I get it like [this](https://gunnarpeipman.com/dotnet-core-worker-service/). From  [this](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/3.1) I am not sure what I need to download left or right section moreover 100's of links are there on that page. Thank you.

Comment: In your VS 2019 installation, did you choose to include the .NET Core workload? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio?view=vs-2019

Comment: I have chosen. Now from File-->New-->Project getting Worker Service template. But [this](https://medium.com/@nickfane/introduction-to-worker-services-in-net-core-3-0-4bb3fc631225) and [this](https://wakeupandcode.com/worker-service-in-asp-net-core/) way not getting. To create worker service do I need must need to add WS template as show in given articles(from asp.net core project)?

Comment: I have selected o top .NET Core and ASP.NET Coer 3.1. As per the screenshot from above url.

Comment: Can you follow https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#worker-service-template instead?

Answer (score 2):

> How to add .NET Core to Visual Studio 2015 Pro

TL;DR: you can't.

.NETCore 3.0 (now end of life) and 3.1 are only supported in VS 2019.

.NET Core 2.2 (the only other supported version) is only supported in VS 2017 & 2019.